# problema con vue: vue/valid-template-root

Tags: html, css, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por que esos errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi estructura de código

Comment: Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código como texto.

Answer (score 0):

El primer error se debe a que no has agregado el componente en el `template`. Más info [acá](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-11)

**Ejemplo:**

```
<script>
import ChildComp from './ChildComp.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ChildComp
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <ChildComp />
</template>
```

---

El segundo error se debe a que el nombre de todos los componentes debe ser multi-palabra, excepto la raiz (`App`) y los provistos por `Vue`. Más info [acá](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/multi-word-component-names.html)

**Ejemplo:**

```
<script>
/* ✓ GOOD */
export default {
  name: 'SignUp',
  // ...
}
</script>
```